# php count images in directory and show/output as number array

Tags: php, arrays, image, count

As the title says what I'm trying to do is count the number of images in a directory and output it as numbers so for example if there are 4 images I want the result to be:

```
01 | 02 | 03 | 04
```

I have this so far:

```
$count = glob('images/{*.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($count as $filecount) {

 echo '<li><a href="#" id="' . $filecount . '">' . $filecount . '</a></li>';

}
```

which outputs path/filename.jpg but haven't a clue on how to convert that to a numbers array or even if i'm in the right ballpark.

As usual all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the index. `foreach ($count AS $index => $filecount)`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work great, though had to write an "if" statement to remove the 0 count :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That array is numerically indexed (`0` to *length`-1`* ), use it to obtain the number:

```
foreach($count as $index => $filecount) {
    $number = $index+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($count as $index => $filecount) {
      // $number is "01" for the first and "02" for second etc
      $number = str_pad($index, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      //...
 }
```